# Not too sure why my keyListener does not work here

Tags: java, keylistener

**Code:**

```
    public class Panel extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
    //variable for coordinates:
    private final int a1 = 155; 
    private final int a2 = (790-a1);
    private final int a5 = 47;
    private boolean gameStarted = false;
    private int rotated = 0;
    ArrayList<TetrisBlocks> blocks = new ArrayList<TetrisBlocks>();

    public Panel() //constructor
    { 
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1440,790)); //sets the size of the window displayed
        setBackground(Color.blue); //sets background color to blue (of the JPanel)
        setLayout(new SpringLayout()); //sets the layout of the text
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);

        //adds text for Game:
        add(printText("            Horizontal Tetris"));
        add(printText("                                                                  Score:"));

        //creates arrayList of Tetris Blocks:

        for (int i = 0; i <1; i++){
            blocks.add(new TetrisBlocks(1));
        }

    }

    public boolean getValue(){
        return gameStarted;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g); //overrides the paint method
        Graphics2D graphicsA = (Graphics2D) g; //creates a new Graphics 2D object

    }

    public JLabel printText(String input){
        JLabel jlabel1 = new JLabel(input); //create a new label for the text
        jlabel1.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.BOLD,40)); //set font type and size
        return jlabel1; //return statement for the method
    }

    public void AutomaticMove(){
        int x = 1;
        while (x <= 6){
            repaint();
            if (rotated == 1 || rotated == 3){
                blocks.get(0).MoveY();
            } else{
                blocks.get(0).MoveX(); 
            }
            x+=1;
            try { //gives computer a 1 second delay before moving the block again
                Thread.sleep(500); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { //throws and catches the exception when the sleep is interrupted
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            System.out.println("Right key typed");
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            System.out.println("Left key typed");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            System.out.println("Right key pressed");
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            System.out.println("Left key pressed");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            System.out.println("Right key Released");
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            System.out.println("Left key Released");
        }
    }
}
```

Been trying a lot of different things but key listener just wouldn't respond to my input on the keyboard. Any suggestions or ideas why this might be true? I've tried many other sources online but still can't figure out why key listener does not work on my program. There is nothing wrong with my IDE or my computer because other codes using keylistener works just fine.

Comment: This is just a guess, so I'm making it a comment instead of an answer. You're adding your keyListener to this panel, but do key events get to the panel? I'm used to adding keyListener to the frame, so that the frame gets events when the frame has focus. Perhaps your panel gets key events only when it has focus.

Comment: Welcome to SO. TL;DR. Pleas post [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It's working good but you have problem in your `Automatic Move` part of code,when I erased that part it worked without issue. Look at the picture :

[image]

You can test it with this code :

```
private final int a1 = 155;
private final int a2 = (790 - a1);
private final int a5 = 47;
private boolean gameStarted = false;
private int rotated = 0;
ArrayList<TetrisBlocks> blocks = new ArrayList<TetrisBlocks>();

public JTableTest() // constructor
{
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1440, 790)); // sets the size of the
                                                // window displayed
    setBackground(Color.blue); // sets background color to blue (of the
                                // JPanel)
    setLayout(new SpringLayout()); // sets the layout of the text
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);

    // adds text for Game:
    add(printText("Horizontal Tetris"));
    add(printText("Score:"));

    // creates arrayList of Tetris Blocks:

}

public boolean getValue() {
    return gameStarted;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); // overrides the paint method
    Graphics2D graphicsA = (Graphics2D) g; // creates a new Graphics 2D
                                            // object

}

public JLabel printText(String input) {
    JLabel jlabel1 = new JLabel(input); // create a new label for the text
    jlabel1.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 40)); // set font type
                                                            // and size
    return jlabel1; // return statement for the method
}



@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        System.out.println("Right key typed");
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        System.out.println("Left key typed");
    }

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        System.out.println("Right key pressed");
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        System.out.println("Left key pressed");
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        System.out.println("Right key Released");
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        System.out.println("Left key Released");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JTableTest tb = new JTableTest();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setPreferredSize(frame.getMaximumSize());
    frame.add(tb);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you copy and paste the part of the code that was causing the problem? The picture is a little blurry and I cannot see which part of the code caused the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Hellboy yes, just delete that part and add your panel in JFrame it will work

Comment: @Hellboy If you add your TetrisBlocks class we can help you more than this.

Comment: I'm sorry, which section of the Automatic Move method did you erase to get it working?

Comment: Yes, that worked out fine, but I do need a method similar to my old Automatic Move method to make sure the game works. Any ideas on how I could change the old Automatic Move method so that this code works?

Comment: @Hellboy I remind you again we don't know what in your TetrisBlock code